# Find polygon in grid line network PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon

I have a grid line table to use as the blade for splitting my polygon table in PostGIS with a ST_Split method. It works fine but now I want to find which parts of polygons are located within my grid.I thought about using ST_Centroid to find the centroid of split parts and then applying ST_Within. My question is: can I apply these two steps in one SQL query or should I compute centroid first and then use ST_whitin? Or is there anything else to do this?
Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    gridpoly.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        st_centroid(gridpoly.geom) 
    FROM gridpoly) as center
JOIN 
    ( SELECT geom FROM gridline As cells WHERE col=1 AND row=2 ) as line
ON ST_Within(center.geom,line.geom)
```

The gridpoly table is the result of the split function which contains polygons. But in this code I don't have any column as 'center'.

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the centroid geometry, you must name it otherwise the column is called st_centroid

```
st_centroid(gridpoly.geom) as geom
```

Note that you can't `select gridpoly.*` because `gridpoly` is not in the from clause. You can only use `center.*` and/or `line.*`. To get access to the `gridpoly` data, you need to join it. Maybe fetch the `gridpolyID` at the same time as the centroid so you can join on it.

At last, the query will likely return nothing as the polygon centroid is typically not **within** the cut line. It would work if you have cells (as polygons) instead of lines.

Comment: Thanks, @JGH. You are right, the result of ST_Whitin is always false. So how can I find polygons in my grid?

Comment: You can use `ST_Envelope(ST_Collect(line.geom))` to create a polygon with the bounding box of your lines. This should work if they form a regular closed grid. Otherwise, look at `ST_Polygonize()`.

Answer (score 0):

To find which polygon sections are within my grid line, I created another grid with polygon type and then used them to check polygon contained in my new grid network.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    gridpoly
JOIN
    ( SELECT * from gridpolygon WHERE col=1 AND row=2 ) as line
ON ST_Within(gridpoly.result, line.geom)
```